# Is Meshlab affected by the Log4j vulnerability

Tags: log4j, meshlab

My employer wants to know if MeshLab is affected by the Log4j vulnerability. Could someone help me out? Does Meshlab use Log4J at all?

PS. I really know nothing about programming so "for dummies" answers only, please. Thx

Answer (score 2):

If you check the source code on Github

https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/blob/f3568e75c9aed6da8bb105a1c8ac7ebbe00e4536/src/common/GLLogStream.h

Meshlab does not use Log4J, looks like they created their on logger.

Comment: Can confirm. Meshlab uses its own logger based on Qt. Also, Log4j is written in java languaje, and meshlab is written in C++.